# How can I make this type of gradient in drawables?

Tags: android, gradient

I use the gradient type as sweep but the `startColor` starts from 3 O'clock, how can I change the angle?

[image: This is the picture.]

Comment: just rotate your drawable/view

Comment: @VladMatvienko when I rotate view,there will be blank spaces around the view

Comment: add code in questions

Answer (score 1):

remove angle from the code and give android:centerY="0.5"and android:centerX="0.5" your problem will be resolved.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:type="sweep"
    android:centerColor="#FA364D"
    android:endColor="#212545"
    android:startColor="#212545" 
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:centerX="0.5"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: I didnt use 'angle', and 'android:cenerX' and 'android:centerY' didnt work.

Comment: did you attend the angle in my question image?

Answer (score 0):

Set start and end color same and different center color and set centerX and centerY to 0.5

try this one

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
    android:type="sweep"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:centerX="0.5"
    android:centerColor="#303F9F"
    android:endColor="#3F51B5"
    android:startColor="#3F51B5" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <gradient
        android:type="sweep"
        android:startColor="#212545"
        android:centerColor="#FA364D"
        android:endColor="#212545"/>
</shape>
```

and I created `TextView` with above background and `android:rotation="135"` and `android:scaleX="99"` and `android:scaleY="99"`.